# Delete a image in a ImaveView programmatically created using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, setbackground

I need to display a different image according to a condition. The problem is that the previous image remains visible under the next image?

I have nowhere found using the correct command to delete the previous image before displaying the next one.

```
private fun showDecision(warning: String) {
        var imgResId = 0
        var resId = 0

        // accessing our custom image which we have in drawable folder
        when (warning) {
            "wrong" -> {
                imgResId = R.drawable.wrong
                resId = imgResId
            }
            "notGood" -> {
                imgResId = R.drawable.notGood
                resId = imgResId
            }
            "bad" -> {
                imgResId = R.drawable.bad
                resId = imgResId
            }
        }

        // image de l'arbitre
        val decisionView = ImageView(this)
        // setting height and width of imageview
        decisionView.layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(392, 700)
        decisionView.x = hut.x - 80 // setting margin from left
        decisionView.y = aDecision.y // setting margin from top

        // accessing our relative layout from activity_main.xml
        decisionLayout = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.decision_layout)
        decisionView.setImageResource(resId)

        // Add ImageView to linearLayout
        decisionLayout?.addView(decisionView) // adding image to the layout
        decisionLayout?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        decisionShown = true
    }
```

*setBackgroundResource(0)* does nothing.

Before that, in my onClick(view: View?) I use GONE as below

```
   if (decisionShown) {
        decision_layout.visibility = View.GONE
        decisionShown = false
    }
```

What did I not do correctly? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can clear imageview content by calling **setImageDrawable(null);**

```
imgView.setImageDrawable(null);
```

such usage is documented in the official docs: [ImageView#setImageDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) .

Comment: Hey Happy Singh, tanks but it doesn't work for me. I did "decisionView.setImageDrawable(null)" juste the line before "decisionView.x = hut.x - 80". But I got the new image superposed on the first one as I said :-(

Answer (score 0):

The right instruction is `view.removeAllViews()` for me and it works. Why "AllViews"? Just because it could be some views, not only the one preceded.